# Inspiron 7520 Power Management 12.10 after sleep mode

Tags: 12.10, ati, power-management

I use an inspiron 7520; i7 3rd generation, AMD Radeon HD 7730m w/ intel 4000hd

I have noticed that my batttery life radically change when I awake my computer from sleep. When I just boot yp my computer, I have close 4 hours battery life, then if i awake the computer I have 2 hours. Weird eh?

oh by the way! I am using Jupiter to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of "sleep", one where it retains memory and trickles power and the other thats saves the memory to hard disk and totally shuts down.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pm-action.8.html

Might be the reason? Using wrong "sleep"?

Comment: At the moment, I am using the suspend "sleep", so I should go hybrid? But how can I change it?

Comment: Try the commands one t a time and see the effect. But Id try the pm-hybernate one first to see if your battery doesnt loose so much charge

Comment: I tried, it is the hybrid hibernate that works best

Comment: Good, a solution, now to test it long term

Comment: I did. how can I switch the pm setting?

Comment: Don't know, sorry